# How to match fingerprint data with all saved fingerprints data on database saved using select query c#

Tags: c#

I can match fingerprints by using select query and condition "where id".
But I want to identify the id by using fingerprint.

Or
1- In what data type we can save fingerprint data in a table using mysql database c#.
or
2-can we convert fingerprint binary data into some unique data for matching and save in the database.
3- how to identify fingerprint data with all saved fingerprint of database with unique data of fingerprint data (saved in the database).
for example.
string sSql="select id,name from fingerprint_table where fingerprint_data=" (unique data saved in the database)"
Note: i do not know how to match or compare fingerprint data with all saved fingerprint of database.

Comment: Maybe ask the one who put the fingerprints into your database? I don't think we will be able to tell you how to match data we don't know.

Comment: Assuming you have a FingerPrint Table
Id     (int)// Primary Key
FingerPrintData (LONGBLOB)                                                                                                    how to match current fingerprint data with all saved fingerprint data of database  in the select query. I want like this select query                                                                              string query="select id from fingerprinttable where fingerprintdata="currentfingerdata""; sir is it possible? or any other easy method to solve my issue

Comment: This is a big project, and an "ordinary" database is not up to the task.  Have you ever watched those CSI episodes where fingerprints are matched by picking specific points on the fingerprint and drawing polygons between them?  Some of that is done for dramatic effect, but it's not entirely wrong; there's a whole science for this that goes way beyond simple database matches.

Comment: How to convert fingerprint data to unique id and save it into database then use it for searching in database. Is it possible?